# What will the user = UserClass(request.form['username'] , request.form['password']) possible error be?

Tags: python, mysql

My platform is PythonAnywhere.com. My case project is based on two columns; username and password fields. I am doing Python Flask-Alchemy with MySql databases. The thing I want is to add a user to MySql database from a Python web application using a POST method.

The MySql Database structure is like this:

**id**

**username**

**password_hash**

```
            <form action="." method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter your username" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
            </form>
```

And The Python application app.py code it this:

```
class UserClass(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(128))
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    #email = db.Column(db.String(128))
    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)
    def get_id(self):
        return self.username


@app.route('/register' , methods=['GET','POST'])

def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template('register.html')
    user = UserClass(request.form['username'] , request.form['password'])
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    #flash('User successfully registered')
    return redirect(url_for('login_page.html'))
```

I go into trouble at this line, and it appears at error log:

```
user = UserClass(request.form['username'] , request.form['password'])
```

This event error occurs when I hit the **register** link from **main_page.html**, and it redirects from main_page.html to the **error log**. Keep in mind that the error occurs **before** the register form appears. And the register.html does not appear. This is a 'POST' method. When I change to the 'GET' method, the form register.html appears.

What will the user = UserClass(request.form['username'] , request.form['password'])  possible error be? Any possibilities for coding technique would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: there are a lot of tutorials that cover that see for example https://codeshack.io/login-system-python-flask-mysql/ give it a try and when you got a specific question ask

Comment: Hi nbk, thank you for your link. However, what in my platform is about the SqlAlchemy with MySQL database adding records.

Comment: there are similar tutorials for sqlalchemy as well please search for it, they will give you much insight into the topic